# I can't login mysql server on mac

Tags: mysql, macos

I installed mysql on mac.
when I access the mysql. 
terminal showed 'bash: mysql: command not found'
So I changed the setting

go to /usr/bin directory

sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql mysql

then

ls -l mysql

=> lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  26  3  7 12:23 mysql -> /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql

next I access the mysql server

something wrong

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'kimjaeyeon'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How cant I solve the this problem??

Answer (score 0):

You did not enter a password when mysql says `using password: NO` that means there is a password for the user and it was not entered

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'kimjaeyeon'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

This error was caused because You did not enter your password

Or try this:

`$ mysql -h localhost -u kimjaeyeon -p`

To check if the mysql server is running:

`$ ps auxf | grep mysql`

Comment: Thank you.I try to. 
it can't 
I not set on mysql password

Comment: please try it now @김재연

Answer (score 0):

After checking if the mysql server is running, please try using `-p` option, which asks you to enter a password, like

`$ mysql -h localhost -u kimjaeyeon -p`

To check if the mysql server is running:

`$ ps auxf | grep mysql`